# Response after insert data in database using angularjs and php

Tags: php, angularjs

I am trying to save data in a database using $http.post with angularjs.
Data is saving in db but I'm not able to track its success response.

Below is my HTML code.

```
<form ng-controller="studentCntrl" name="add_user">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title">Add a user by sending an invite via e-mail</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_email" ng-model="user_name" placeholder="Enter a name">
                <br />
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_name" ng-model="user_email" placeholder="Enter an e-mail adress">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <!-- <button type="" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="add_user()">Invite</button> -->
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" name="add_user" value="Invite" ng-click="save_user()">
            <button class="btn btn-warning">Cancel</button>
        </div>
</form>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module("student_app", []);
app.controller("studentCntrl", function($scope, $http){
    $scope.save_user = function() {

    $http.post("insert.php",   {'user_name':$scope.user_name,'user_email':$scope.user_email}).success(function(data,status){
    console.log(data);
console.log("Data Inserted Successfully");
});}});
```

insert.php

```
<?php 
include('db.php');
switch($_GET['action'])  {
    case 'add_user' :
        add_user(); 
        break;
}

function add_user() {

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")); 
$user_name      = $data->user_name;    
$user_email     = $data->user_email;


$qry = mysql_query('INSERT INTO register(name, user_email) VALUES ("' . $user_name  . '","' . $user_email . '")');}?>
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong.
Hope you guys can help me.
Thanks..

Comment: to read the response you have to print some msg on server side

Comment: I am using console.log(data) 
    $http.post("insert.php",   {'user_name':$scope.user_name,'user_email':$scope.user_email}).success(function(data,status){
    console.log(data);  but its not console anything.

Comment: i mean do something like this in your add_user() function  if($qry) { echo "success"; } else { echo "fail"; }

Comment: I did the same, it echo response but not in ".success(function(data,status){
    console.log(data)"

Answer (score 0):

In the **insert.php** file, add the below lines after inserting data into the database.

```
    if($qry){
      echo "success";
    }else{
       echo "Something went wrong";
    }
```

Comment: I did the same, it echo response but not in ".success(function(data,status){
    console.log(data)"